# Can this be true? $\exists x P(x) \wedge \exists x \neg P(x) $

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Can the following be true or is it a contradiction?

$
\exists x P(x) \wedge \exists x \neg P(x)
$

Sorry if this is an obvious question, i'm new to this topic.

Comment: "there exists an odd number **and** there exists a not-odd (i.e. even) number"

Comment: Hint. What about the sentence "there is an even integer and there is an odd integer"?

Comment: For a contradiction you must have $∃xP(x)∧ ¬∃xP(x)$ i.e. $∃xP(x)∧ \forall x ¬P(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important point is that the two $x$s are different.  They are each dummy variables that extend from the $\exists$ to the $P(x)$.  A far better way to write the sentence is $$\exists x P(x) \wedge \exists y \neg P(y)$$  This is logically equivalent to your expression, but it avoids the confusion caused by reusing variables.  In this version, it is easy to see that the sentence can be true,

Answer (score 0):

Of course this can be true. Example:-

> P(x) : x is prime

Answer (score 0):

Consider $P(x)$ be the statement that "$x \in\mathbb R$ and $x=1$".